# bootstrap import effecting all other css design

Tags: html, css, vue.js, bootstrap-4

So i am working a project using vue js. There are different components to my project one component is SignUp which is a sign up page. For validation purposes i installed bootstrap to use form check and form group. But after using it i realize now my all other components design has been destroyed.... the tutorial i followed imported bootstrap in main.js but even if i try to import it now to component SignUp all other design is still not as it should be.

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
```

signUp component

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="text"> Full Name </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model.trim="$v.name.$model" :class="{
                 'is-invalid' :$v.name.$error, 'is-valid':!$v.name.$invalid
                 }">
                <div class="valid-feedback"> Your name is valid! </div>
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    <span v-if="!$v.name.required"> Your name is required. </span>
                    <span v-if="!$v.name.minLength"> Name must have at least {{$v.name.$params.minLength.min}} letters. </span>
                    <span v-if="!$v.name.maxLength"> Name must have at most {{$v.name.$params.maxLength.max}} letters. </span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

#### before import of bootstrap

[image]

#### after import of bootstrap

[image]

the css design breaks

Comment: Can you show 'before' and 'after' screenshots?

Comment: @Anatoly just added before and after and this is just one example.. i have 6 more components files that are affected

Comment: I suppose you should not use bootstrap for validation only. It's all about to design the whole app not just one form or a couple of inputs. Try to use standalone validation packages.

Comment: @Anatoly is there any way that you can import bootstrap in style tag of that component and for my css part of that component to take precedence over it .. I dont understand why does it break style of other components...

Comment: to import within the style tag you can use `scss` style tags and use `@import` statements

Answer (score 0):

There are many options in my opinion the easiest one would be to shift the import bootstrap statement into the component

```
import  Vue from "Vue"
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
```

but this will still mess up your ui when you use the component with other components i recon. But if you using components individually then its cool

Think about importing bootstrap in `scoped styles` for better encapsulation
[check out scoped css to restrict css within the component](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#mixing-local-and-global-styles)

PS:Well if you only want to use bootstrap for the form component you should look into using bootstrap mixins and import only form related css

Comment: Yes i am using components with other components .. i wanted to know that if i import this bootstrap file in my style tag of a component how i can make sure that my css design takes precedence over it.

Comment: use scoped css . i believe scss has @import . and import your css after bootstrap usually that does the trick but not for all elements [check precedence-css-order-css-matters](https://css-tricks.com/precedence-css-order-css-matters/)